# Punctuation at the end of table headings and figure captions

Tags: punctuation

**Let's say we have a figure caption as follows:**

Figure 6. Rehabilitation use between heart attack patients treated with different methods. HA - heart attack, M - method, PT - physical therapy, CI - confidence interval

**Should this caption end with a punctuation or not?**

Comment: There is such thing as "a punctuation" in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a question of taste or of editorial policy. A one sentence caption may end with a stop or no stop. A two sentence caption such as your example necessarily has a stop at the end of the first. For consistency it then seems best also to end the second with a stop. This seems even more desirable when there is punctuation within the second sentence - your example is well filled with commas and it seems odd not to complete the punctuation sequence with a stop.